# Why does bridge edge tools remove top and bottom faces?

Tags: modeling

I have two faces of mesh that I am using with bridge edge tools:

[image]

However, when I go to use the tool, it ends up like this:

[image]

I could go and manually close the 3D mesh. But I am curious as to why this happens in the first place?

[image]

Comment: That's curious.. I've copied your mesh as closely as I can, and can't yet reproduce this behaviour. Could you share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: I have uploaded my file to this post. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: select contours only

Comment: @lemon Dooooh! .. the muscle-memory took over and I didn't even explore the 'wrong' option.

Comment: @RobinBetts This is in the documentation (just checked by curiosity): https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html

Comment: @lemon cheers! edited in. It's one of those things I just got used to.. a nice bit of Blender UI elegance. I never actually read the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you execute *Bridge Edge Loops* on *faces*, the operation will [empty the region-boundaries](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html#examples). (This makes it convenient to tunnel through manifold meshes):

[image]

If instead, you select a boundary edge, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> Select Similar > Amount of Faces Around an Edge, then you're bridging *edges*, not faces:

[image]

.. the faces are then 'not involved' in the calculation.